# How did temperature exist at the moment of Big Bang?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, temperature, big-bang

As we know at the moment of big bang ($10^{-43}$ seconds or Planck time) the temperature was $10^{32}~\rm K$. I hope for temperature to exist there should be some medium or matter needed.

- Is it possible for temperature to exist even without particles?
- How big bang temperature existed before even the particle getting
  created?

Comment: [The Zeroth Law of Thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroth_law_of_thermodynamics) provide the foundation for the concept of temperature. This law does not talk about "masses" being in equilibrium, but of **systems** being that. So if you have two **systems**, and there is no spontaneous energy transfer between them, then they are of the same temperature. From this I believe it is possible to calculate a temperature of the system that is the universe at the Planck Time.

Comment: Have   a look at this link http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/expand.html . It uses the concept that particles and radiation (black body radiation)  exchange energy.  Temperature can be derived from the radiation and thus a connection exists with the early radiation universe of the Big Bang.